# Android app does not appear in some area

Tags: android, google-play, appearance

I published android application on the market in last month. But it does not appear in Mongolia and China if I search. It is OK for Korean, American users and it has been dowloaded more than 100 times since its deployment. My app name is "Delden dictionary". When I search on the Play market "Delden dictionary", everything shows up for the korean users. From Mongolia if I search same as below result shows me that search result is "0".

What is the problem with it?

Please help.

Comment: I think you should add more information when you upload app to GGplay. Is there some filter?

Comment: No there was not any extra filter except for "Rest for the world, except for" option which is checked. And other this option there are country names. But none of them is checked. Thank you for your reply.